# Is Data Object on openPGP smartcard v2 encrypted?

Tags: encryption, pgp, cryptography, smartcard, token

Currently I thinking about on-the-fly disk encryption using Truecrypt/dmcrypt LUKS with key stored on smartcard.
I would like to use openPGP v2 smart card, respectively GPF Cryptostick which is based on openPGP v2 smartcard and my question is:

On the card you can store 3 GPG keys (encryption, signing, authentication) or S/MIME equivalent.
There are also a data objects on smartcard when you can store key for TC/LUKS.
So, are those data objects stored on card encrypted with GPG/S-MIME or just protected by smartcard's PIN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discussed this question also on security forum and here is the answer.

[See answer here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/11322/is-data-object-on-openpgp-smartcard-v2-encrypted)